# I've renamed a bunch of tables in Access on the back-end and the front-end isn't reflecting those changes. Quick fix?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I tried using the link manager but it didn't work. I changed the names of a bunch of BE tables because they just didn't reflect their content (taking over DB from previous DBA, so it's a mess). Is there a quick way to make the FE tables link back to their BE counterparts?

There are also queries and forms that I assume I will need to edit as well.

Answer (score 0):

The link manager did work but it doesn't add new tables which your renamed tables are.

So just link the new tables, and either rename the linked table names or adjust all your queries etc. to the default linked table name.